# CsvMappingException: Too many entries: expected at most 5 (value #5 (7 chars) "&#20013")

Tags: spring, spring-boot, csv, jackson

I have to import an csv file which has tags and they use the same seperator for some strings. Is there a solution to avoid these error messages?

***CsvMappingException: Too many entries: expected at most 5 (value #5 (7 chars) "&#20013")***

Example from csv file:

```
 column1;<request>text;text2;text3;20013</reqest>; <response></repoonse>;
```

Comment: Did you try to escape `;` within tokens?

Comment: How should I do this? Would this not escape every seperator?

Comment: the correct way is to use proper-formatted CSV. If a string between separators contains separator characters then it should be encapsulated into `" "` -- `column1;"<request>text;text2;text3;20013</reqest>"; <response></repoonse>`;